# Laptop Asus X5DC(2010) can't boot no more after formatting win 7 main disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

This laptop had win 7 installed and I decided to install a light Linux distro since it's quite old and slow. I tried a couple distro but they where really slow in every task (even opening the drawer or a folder) so I kept trying new distro since in a certain point of time in the past months (it's like months that i try to fix this laptop and I tried every trick in the book since I troubleshoot often) i couldn't no more boot properly any os's at all.

The installation process from a bootable stick always work but when I reach the "remove the bootable medium and press enter" prompt the pc reboots and the only bootable medium is network. If I enter the boot menu with "esc" key and select the hdd it always says "insert a proper boot media and press enter".

The bios of this machine is super limited, can't chose between legacy/uefi or ahci/ide etc..
I tried everything, even flash the newest bios available (minor change), tried to install os's through an usb-sata adapter because I read that that a dead disk controller could be the cause of this behavior but with no success. I tried another disk even. The one time i tried to install windows xp i got this error: "setupldr couldn't open drive multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)"

I don't really know what to try at this point; an old man gave me this pc to make it a little faster and in years of doing this minor works with pc's I have never been stuck for so long and i feel bad for this man. He can't afford a new one and i would like to fix this one instead of throwing it from the window.

Edit:
Specs are:

- Processor: Intel Celeron 220 1 x 1.2 GHz
- Graphics adapter: ATI Radeon HD 3200
- Display: 15.60 inch 16:9, 1366 x 768 pixel
- HDD: 320GB sata
- RAM: 4 gigs

Comment: Please [edit] and post the hardware specifications so we can start with something concrete rather than an old laptop that had Windows 7.

Comment: And I suggest reading this https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-X5DC-SX025V.36099.0.html . Please understand those reviews were written when the model was new. Nothing you can do now, Windows or Linux, will improve that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I guess it is crap but now it's become a matter of principle: why isn't it possible [to boot no more]?

Comment: It's anyone's guess. The most likely problem is a failed HDD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i tried another 2.5" HDD and the same occured

Comment: Again, it's anyone's guess. Start by troubleshooting what you can have some control over: Reset BIOS, try a proper distro (e.g. AntiX 64-bit) after assuring you have a known good drive properly identified in BIOS and adjust the boot order. BTW, you have the old BIOS (pre-~2012) so "legacy" doesn't make any sense whatsoever. And because of that, even if not a requirement for Linux (it is for Windows) in BIOS make sure you have the old partitioning table as MBR instead of GPT. Of course, at this point everything can fail as before, all it take is one swollen capacitor...